# Button activity with viewPager?

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-viewpager

Please don't judge me, i'm extremely new on android developing... I wanna make an app with viewPager... I've got three pages with three different layouts... But i just couldn't figure out how to deal with a button on second page on viewPager. I found this question " [How to write button onClick method in viewpager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698789/how-to-write-button-onclick-method-in-viewpager) " and set my codes like this:

**ViewPagerAdapter:**

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem( View pager, int position )
{
    View v = new View(pager.getContext());
    LayoutInflater inflater =
            (LayoutInflater) pager.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    int resId = 0;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:         
        resId = R.layout.deneme;            
        break;
    case 1:
        resId = R.layout.deneme2;          
        break;
    case 2:
        resId = R.layout.deneme3;
        break;   
    }

    v = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
    ((ViewPager) pager).addView(v, 0);

    return v;
  }
```

Here I'm getting errors: 
"The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}" on line

```
 LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout2);
```

and "The method getResources() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}" on line

```
 l.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background));
```

**Main:**

```
 public class ViewPagerProjectActivity extends Activity {

 Button btn;
 View deneme2lout;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter( this );
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById( R.id.viewpager );
    pager.setAdapter( adapter );
    pager.setCurrentItem(0);


    LayoutInflater getView = getLayoutInflater();
    deneme2lout = (View) getView.inflate(R.layout.deneme2,null);      
    btn = (Button) deneme2lout.findViewById(R.id.button1);

}

public void buttonClick(View v) {
    if(v.equals(btn)) {
    deneme2lout.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background));
    }
}

 }
```

So as i get, i cannot use those two codes... So how should i do it? I need to change background of the second page when clicked the button on second layout.

**And here's my deneme2.xml codes:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_x="69dp"
        android:layout_y="174dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:text="Change" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because, as it explains, OnClickListener doesn't have these two methods which you're using inside an OnClickListener. Replace:

```
LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout2);
```

with

```
LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.layout2);
```

if it then says v should be final, that should be okay. And replace:

```
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background)
```

with

```
ViewPagerAdapter.this.context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked =) 
But now, i'm getting NullPointerException on this line:
    btn.setOnClickListener( ... );
That's probably because i'm not on the same layout with button... But couldn't figure out how to fix it... Any suggestions?

Comment: hmm, well you are still using the view `v` so it should be fine... you're sure button1 and layout2 exist in that layout?

Also, your code currently doesn't actually add View `v` with the OnClickListener set to the page, it adds View `view`. Try changing it so it adds `v` for the top case and `view` for the bottom two cases and see if it works then.

Comment: You're right :) I've made the changes that you mentioned, and now it doesn't give any error... But on click it's not changing background as well :/ What else should i do? (Sorry for disturbing this much, but as i said i'm very new on android)

Comment: no worries! I can't at the moment see why it wouldn't work. Could you update all the code in the question with what you have now, and post your deneme.xml file (or whichever file contains layout2) please?

Comment: hmm, that's really strange as I still can't see why it wouldn't work. Try changing `l.setBackgroundDrawable(ViewPagerAdapter.this.context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background));` to `l.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);`, it shouldn't make any difference but you never know!

Comment: Didn't work, too. Should i make any activity? or something? As i see, it's suppose to work like this but..?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with the viewpager. It doesn't allow button clicks.

Answer (score 2):

As for the second part of your question, it's simple! Although you now use View `v` all along, you still "overwrite" it with a new inflation at the end:

```
int resId = 0;
switch (position) {
case 0:         
    resId = R.layout.deneme;

    break;
case 1:
    resId = R.layout.deneme2;
    // Inflate v the first time
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.deneme2, null, false);
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    final AbsoluteLayout l = (AbsoluteLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.layout2);  
    // Add the OnClickListener to the button, which is associated with the above instance of v       
    btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View m) {
            l.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
        }
    });
    break;
case 2:
    resId = R.layout.deneme3;
}

// Overwrite the instance of v with the OnClickListener with one without the OnClickListener
v = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
((ViewPager) pager).addView(v, 0);

return v;
```

So, changing the following bits should make it work perfectly:

- Change `View v = new View(pager.getContext());` to `View v = null;`
- Change the final inflation (just before adding the view) to `if (v == null) v = inflater.inflate(resId, null);`

Comment: But may i ask if is there a way to deal with button click in main class, not in PagerAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

In response to your most recent question, you can set an onClick listener outside of the adapter and within the activity like this:

```
public void buttonClick(View v) {
    //do something

}
```

In your xml containing the button, make sure you have android:onClick="buttonClick" as 1 of the properties.

In your xml containing the button, make sure you have android:onClick="buttonClick" as 1 of the properties.

**Edit --**
I don't think you applied the changes I suggested from your most recent code... here is what I was thinking:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter( this );
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById( R.id.viewpager );
    pager.setAdapter( adapter );
    pager.setCurrentItem(0);


    LayoutInflater getView = getLayoutInflater();
    deneme2lout = (View) getView.inflate(R.layout.deneme2,null);      

}

public void buttonClick(View v) {
    deneme2lout.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background));
}
```

If that's not it, then please let us know the error so we can lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Could u check my answer please? i post my codes re-ordered as you said... But still not working.

Comment: I assume you're still having problems because youre getting a NullPointer exception at the if statement. You do not need to add an if statement in the buttonClick method to check if the view is the btn (it's redundant). The buttonClick method will be called if someone clicks that button. Because of this, I think deneme2lout.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.background); should be fine.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: I tried, and didn't work... and i edit my codes, you can check it there... thanks in advance!

Comment: Noep, didn't work out... It's not given any error, but onclick it's not working as well.