# Implementing button in pageradapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, imagebutton

I have been working on the implementation of buttons to update a textview within my pageadapter. This is the code I have thus far for my pageadapter

```
public class CharacterStatsPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}

int maxhp = 0;
View view = null;

public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    switch (position) {
    case 0:

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.characterstats1, null);

        TextView characternamedisplay = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        characternamedisplay.setText(com.echaractersheet.BasicInfo.characternameresult);

        TextView genderdisplay = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        genderdisplay.setText(com.echaractersheet.BasicInfo.genderresult);

        TextView classdisplay = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        classdisplay.setText(com.echaractersheet.BasicInfo.classresult);

        TextView racedisplay = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        racedisplay.setText(com.echaractersheet.BasicInfo.raceresult);

        ImageButton plusmaxhp = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        plusmaxhp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                maxhp = maxhp + 1;
                TextView maxhpdisplay = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
                maxhpdisplay.setText(maxhp);

            }

        });

        break;
    case 1:
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.characterstats2, null);
        break;
    }

    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

    return view;
}
```

The first 4 textviews update perfectly fine but the problem comes in with my imagebutton. When I click the button to update a characters hp, the program force closes and according to logcat, its a null pointer exception and I am unsure why it is happening.

I have been referencing [Button activity with viewPager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099746/button-activity-with-viewpager) and [How to write button onClick method in viewpager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698789/how-to-write-button-onclick-method-in-viewpager) but have been having little success to getting rid of my null pointer exception.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the logcat output so we can see the npe?

Comment: seems adapter code is incomplete, it should implements 'isViewFromObject(View, Object)' probably.

Comment: just checked Your code. Guess Your question should be rephrased to 'why I got maxhpdisplay == null' in 'onClick()'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have fixed Your code.
Please, refer below:

```
public static class CharacterStatsPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}

int maxhp = 0;
View view = null;
View view2 = null;

public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View localView = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page1, null);

            TextView characternamedisplay = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            characternamedisplay.setText(R.string.hello_world);

            TextView genderdisplay = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            genderdisplay.setText(R.string.hello_world);

            TextView classdisplay = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            classdisplay.setText(R.string.hello_world);

            TextView racedisplay = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            racedisplay.setText(R.string.hello_world);

            ImageButton plusmaxhp = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
            plusmaxhp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    maxhp = maxhp + 1;
                    TextView maxhpdisplay = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
                    if (maxhpdisplay != null) { 
                        maxhpdisplay.setText(String.valueOf(maxhp));
                    }
                }

            });
            localView = view;
            break;
        case 1:
            view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page2, null);
            localView = view2;
            break;
    }

    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(localView, 0);

    return localView;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {

    return (view == (View)o);
}
}
```

Seems the issue was in the following: You've used the same variable for both view. If pager at first makes call to obtain first item and later - second one, then Your variable will hold reference to second item which doesn't have textView5 in where.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly! I didn't realize that I needed a separate variable for each view. As for an earlier comment the subsequent public boolean isViewFromObject(...I had it but just didn't post it for some reason :) Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, You don't need these variable. You can, for example call getChildAt(index) to obtain view. Moreover, it might be better not to have views actions processing in the adapter. Btw, I think, adapter might be interpreted as a Model in MVC terminology in some way, and so shouldn't handle user interactions. You could pass handler to it from the activity/fragment.

Comment: I am still learning and am wondering how you would go about doing what you have described. I really don't like the coding in user interactions in the pager adapter, but have been unsuccessful with my limited knowledge in doing it any other way. This pager adapter is just beyond my comprehension. If you have any links to good tutorials to help me better understand I would very much appreciate it! :) Thanks

Comment: You could try to learn about list views and adapters for better understanding of the concept. Checkout http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html it's mimght be a bit complex, but contains lot of useful info about lists and adapters (could be partially applied for ViewPager).